# OnInvalid html event triggering after Required modifier removed through JS

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have three input fields I am attempting to enforce validity on. Currently, I have them all set as `required`, but removing the modifier with Javascript on submit if one of them is filled out; essentially, one must fill out at least one, but not none of these fields.

Here is an example of the fields:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
        var $inputs = $('input[name=Input1],input[name=Input2], input[name=Input3]');
        $inputs.on('input', function () {
            // Set the required property of the other input to false if this input is not empty.
            $inputs.not(this).prop('required', $(this).val().length > 0 && $(this).val() != 0)
        });
    });

jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#Input1, #Input2").oninvalid = (function() {
                $(this).setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid Input1, Input2, or Input3")
            });
        });

    var Input3default = document.getElementById('Input3')
    if (Input3.value.length == 0) Input3.value = "0";
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <form action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">

                <div class="row" style="text-align:justify; width: 100%; display:inline">
                    <div class="">
                        <label for="text3">Input1:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Input1" name="Input1" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1, Input2, or Input3')" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <label for="text4">Input2:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Input2" name="Input2" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1, Input2, or Input3')"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <label for="text5">Input3:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Input3" name="Input3" required placeholder="0" pattern="[0-9]*" onsubmit="Input3default"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input3')"/>
                    </div>

                </div>



                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
                </p>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This seems to work fine if I leave it default; I have Input1 and Input2 empty by default, and Input3 has a value of "0" by default. If I enter Input1 or Input2, my submission goes through just fine. However, the problems begin if I alter Input3.

Problem 1: Any time I enter Inputs 1 and 2 but leave 3 blank, it triggers invalidity; my Input3default never seems to trigger, and it is passed blank and caught by the oninvalid tag.

Problem 2: Along with that, if I do not specify an Input2 along with my Input1 while Input3 is blank, it triggers invalidity on Input2. Using Chrome Debugger, I can see that the `Required` tag is removed, but my OnInvalid pop-up still comes up no matter what is remedied.

Essentially, I am trying to solve the second problem: *When I remove the required html tag from my input, after invalidating another input with a Javascript-enforced default, my inputs refuse to validate on the front end.*

I appreciate any advice and conjecture as to why this may be the case, and believe that the two problems are connected.

EDIT: Upon adding an `=` to my original oninvalid JQuery function, I removed a JS error. It appears that my Input3 default function triggers on pageload, but not on submit; I added an `onsubmit` function to input3, but am still receiving `oninvalid` events for input2.

Comment: `.prop('required', $(this).val().length > 0 && $(this).val() != 0);` try this in the input event handler.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I'm still receiving the same error, but I appreciate your suggestion for improving my validation.

Comment: Please expand your snippet so it properly reproducing your problem.

Comment: I expanded the snippet with code similar to mine (I did not originally put it there, I don't have experience with JS questions or the language in general so much). I'm not sure if it will help.

Comment: It appears that the same issue does persist. Upon `OnInvalid` being triggered, it refuses to accept new input. It also doesn't seem to reproduce my error with Input3, if left empty while Input1 and 2 are filled, triggers invalidity... strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue on my own, using [the OnInput event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp).

The `setCustomValidity` function, when triggered, does not allow a submission while a CustomValidity is set. In order to fix this, I edited my inputs as so:

```
<input type="text" id="Input1" name="Input1" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1, Input2, or Input3')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

I still have a few kinks to iron out, but this fixed my main problem in that the validity of an input was not being reset.

I'll leave this answer unaccepted at first to allow others to pitch in.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question, I just had a similar problem. I didn't realised that the Validity need to be reset every time.